# How can I show a specific known value on the boxplot using R?

Tags: r, boxplot

To be more specific, I have one value as a result of my analysis and I want to show where this specific value correspondence on the related boxplot.
[image: boxplot]

I want to get something like the image. The red point will be the result of my analysis.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use the `points()` function. I.e.  `boxplot(mtcars$mpg);
points(mtcars$mpg[5],col="red",pch=19)` adds the fifth value of the `mtcars$mpg` data on the boxplot.

Comment: Are you using `ggplot2`? Try something like `annotate(geom = "point", x = x0, y = y0, color = "red", size = 2)`, where `x0` and `y0` are the coordinates of that point.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new data frame with the points you want to mark and use `geom_point`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes("", hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(hwy = 30), color = "red")
```

[image: boxplot]